# what is the best practice to set android custom font?

Tags: android, fonts, custom-font

i'm beginner of android and i want to change some control font.

first way:

```
   TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);

   Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/abc.ttf");

   tx.setTypeface(custom_font)
```

this way is not good because you have to find all control to set the font

second way:
 create custom control that extend from target control

```
public class TextViewWithFont extends TextView {

        public TextViewWithFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/abc.ttf")
            this.setTypeface(custom_font);
        }

        public TextViewWithFont(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/abc.ttf")
            this.setTypeface(custom_font);
        }

        public TextViewWithFont(Context context) {
            super(context);
            Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/abc.ttf")
            this.setTypeface(custom_font);
        }
```

third way: use Calligraphy libary

so guys whats you idea? which one is better and do you know other method to change a font?

Comment: I do it by creating and initializing a static TypeFace in Application class. Then use it in everywhere as tx.setTypeface(custom_font)

Comment: Do you want to set this font in layout XML too or just Java.?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran thanks for response.. i want to use in layout xml

Comment: @NishinRaj thanks for your response. could you give me a example that what do you do?

Comment: @hosseinderakhshan Can't add the code as comment, because it wouldn't be clear. So I have added it as an answer.

Comment: Caligraphy is not the only library to that helps with custom fonts. I got different approach here: https://github.com/MarcinOrlowski/Fonty

Answer (score 4):

Here I am just giving some hint, How to use the custom Font in XML layout.

In this Example, I using Roboto font, You change based on your requirement.

First, create your custom font style in your attr like this,

```
   <declare-styleable name="TCTextView">
        <attr name="fontType">
            <enum name="RobotoBold" value="0" />
            <enum name="RobotoBoldItalic" value="1" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
```

Create your Custom TextView like this,

```
public class MKTextView extends TextView {

    public MKTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public MKTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MKTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);

        init(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * To initialize the default value to the component.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     */
    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        Typeface typeface = FontUtil.getTCFont(context, attrs);

        if (typeface != null) {
            setTypeface(typeface);
        }

    }
}
```

Use this Helper Util class to get and set the Custom Fonts

```
public class FontUtil {

    /**
     * To set the custom font based on the attribute settings.
     *
     * @param ctx
     *         Context
     * @param attrs
     *         attribute setting for the components.
     *
     * @return {@link Typeface}
     */
    public static Typeface getTCFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MKTextView);

        int value = a.getInt(R.styleable.MKTextView_fontType, 0);

        final String customFont = getFontName(value);

        a.recycle();

        return getTCFont(ctx, customFont);
    }

    /**
     * Get the Font name in assert folder based in {@link Fonts}
     *
     * @param fonts
     *         {@link Fonts}
     *
     * @return Font name in assert folder
     */
    private static String getFontName(int fonts) {
        final String customFont;
        switch (fonts) {
            case 0:
                customFont = "Roboto-Bold.ttf";
                break;
            case 1:
                customFont = "Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf";
                break;
            default:
                customFont = "Roboto-BoldItalic.ttf";
                break;
        }

        return customFont;
    }

    /**
     * To get the {@link Typeface} based on the font type(in asserts/fonts).
     *
     * @param ctx
     *         Context
     * @param asset
     *         font name in fonts folder
     *
     * @return {@link Typeface}
     */
    private static Typeface getTCFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
        Typeface tf = null;

        try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), "fonts/" + asset);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

        return tf;
    }
}
```

And you can use in your XML layout like this,

```
<in.muthu.stackoverflow.font.MKTextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    app:fontType="RobotoBold"/>
```

Comment: thanks so much for your response.. in this way i have to implement all of my controls like MKTextView.. do you think this is best method? do you have problem with this method or no?

Comment: This is just a Custom View, I am using in all my projects, I never faced any issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is the application class

```
public class AppController extends Application {
    public static Typeface customTF;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        customTF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/custom_font.ttf");

    }

}
```

add class name to application tag in manifest file

```
<application
        android:name=".AppController"
        ...
        ...
        >
```

Use the typeface as

```
tvTitle.setTypeface(AppController.customTF);
```

Comment: thanks so much.. but in this method If I have understood your point we have to find all of my controls in my form and then setTypeface for all of them.. is it true?